# Why progress bar appear after the for loop completely processed

Tags: php, javascript

Following is my script in which I put the progress bar to tell the user about the progress of sheets data being processed the problem is that the progress bar appears after the whole process of saving xls to csv being done kindly let me know how can i modify the following so that progress bar appears correctly right on when the current sheet is on process. Thanks,

```
 $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $excel->setOutputEncoding('UTF-16');
    $excel->read('Student2.xls');
    $x=1;
    $sep = ",";

   $nbSheets = count($excel->sheets);
  echo $x." -  ".$nbSheets;

  $total = $nbSheets - 1;

for($i = 0; $i < $nbSheets; $i++) {


    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';

    // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    // Send output to browser immediately
    flush();
    //sleep(1);

   ob_start();
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[$i]['numRows']) {
        $y=1;
        $row="";
        while($y<=$excel->sheets[$i]['numCols']) {
            $cell = isset($excel->sheets[$i]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[$i]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
            $row.=($row=="")?"\"".$cell."\"":"".$sep."\"".$cell."\"";
            $y++;
        } 
        echo $row."\n"; 
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1; $y = 1;
    $fp = fopen("data.csv",'a');
    fwrite($fp,ob_get_contents());
    fclose($fp);
    ob_end_clean();

}

echo "CSV file created successfully";
// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
```

Comment: You have to use AJAX for this purpose.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar kindly take a look at http://stuff.w3shaman.com/php-progress-bar/ this is working sample.

Comment: Just please, don't use `language="javascript"`. This is not valid.

Comment: Above link I mentioned it contains the same for loop as above, the only difference is the above code contains the script for dumping data  and the link I mentioned doesnot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your problem :

[questions#6556790 : echo-string-while-every-long-loop-iteration-flush-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556790/echo-string-while-every-long-loop-iteration-flush-not-working)

Also why are you using the output buffer for writing in the `data.csv` file ? Output buffer, as it said, is for outputting data so in this case I think it would be more logical to simply pass the `$row."\n"` in the `fwrite` function. Correct me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Nah!! didnot worked in my case more over i cannot use in fwrite cause i am not getting single row in that

Comment: oh ya my mistake, you would need to make an other variable called `$rows` in which you `$rows.=$row."\n";` instead of `echo $row."\n";` and then it should work without the output buffer stuff, I guess.

Comment: well i got into one more trouble and a wierd one no matter what i mention before the piece of code of the for loop, it  runs first. seriously why :-?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use AJAX, or something client-server communications framework, to make this happen.

You could try looking at [this example code](http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/) (download the code via the link near the bottom of the article).

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878161/php-ajax-upload-progress-bar) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160335/php-ajax-progress-indicator) seem to address a similar issue.

Much as I hate to say it, searching "ajax php progressbar" will likely bring up a host of examples.

Comment: I used <body onLoad="run();"> and alert("hi") even hi is appearing after execution of for loop why is that..

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and the link you mentioned. There is one difference in your code and the difference is you have commented the `sleep(1);`, and because of only this command you can not see the working progress bar properly.

So kindly uncomment this `sleep(1);` and your code will work properly.

Comment: I used `<body onLoad="run();">` and `alert("hi")` even hi is appearing after execution of for loop why is that..